# what is the difference and when to use Save in java as Text file or as an Object?

Tags: java, object, graph, save, text-files

I need to save a graph in order to load it and apply algorithms on it ...
so what is best to do save the graph as text file or as an object ?? ...
or is there another efficient way ???

Comment: More info plz: what do you mean by "graph"

Comment: and what kind of algorithms are you applying?

Comment: One saves the data as text -- humanly readable, and the other as a serialized object in binary -- not humanly readable but somewhat more compressed and retaining some logical information.  Another efficient way? Hm, there's xml serialization, but I've never done this myself.

Comment: graph class contains an arraylist of nodes each node class contain an arraylist of edges which links to the other node and the values of the edge

Comment: algorithms are Dijkstra , prim and ford fulkerson

Comment: Hovercraft ... thanks ... is there a difference in the loading or reading speed between the two ways ???

Comment: Loading from a serialized object should be faster but if the content is pretty small then I doubt the difference will be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make your node and edge classes serializable, that will be the easiest thing. You won't have to worry about dealing with circular references on write or reconstructing them on read; they will automatically be reconstituted.

If you use symbolic data, then you will need to have a unique id for each node unless you are guaranteed that no two nodes in the graph will ever have the same data. Then you'll need to maintain a symbol table for reconstructed nodes when you reconstruct the graph. Lots of bookkeeping headaches.